# How to programatically restart another android app?

Tags: android

Firstly, I understand that commonly this is not something that you typically want to do.  However, the app I'm developing adds functionality to another app, but requires that the other app be restarted for it to work.

Is it possible to restart another app (i.e. -> user clicks a confirm button, other app is closed and reopened)?  How would I accomplish this?

If it's not possible normally, would it be possible if the app has SU?  How would it be accomplished then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way that no need root permission.

```
ComponentName componentName = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.xxx.yyy.zzz").getComponent();
Intent intent = IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask(componentName);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I have selected your answer as it is more effective than mine, avoiding the need for root.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to interact with other apps through Android. Usually, intents are used for this.

You can go through [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html) that shows what are the possible things you can do with other apps using your activity.

Especially, see the Lesson: [Sending the User to Another App](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html)

Comment: Thank you for your input!  Unfortunately, that will not allow me to restart the app, only open it (so, if it's already running, it will not have the intended effect).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to uncover an answer... hopefully this will be helpful to those of you looking for the same.

Using [RootTools](https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools), this is very easily done.

```
 RootTools.killProcess(package);
 Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(package);
 startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```